# Proof of Correspondence Theorem for groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Correspondence Theorem : If $G$ is a group and $K ⊴ G$, then $\Phi:\text{Sub}(G;K)\to \text{Sub}(G/K)$ defined by $\Phi(S)=S/K$ is a bijection, and we have that $T \le S \le G$ in $\text{Sub}(G;K) \iff T/K \le S/K,$ in which case $[S:T] =[S/K:T/K]$.

I want to prove that $[S:T] =[S/K:T/K]$.

Claim: $f:S/T \to (S/K)\;/\;(T/K)$ by $f(sT)=\pi(s)T/K$ is a bijection.
$\pi:G \to G/K$ is a natural map.

If $f(aT)=f(bT)$, where $a,b \in S$, then $$\pi(a)T/K=\pi(b)T/K$$

Given $x\in aT$, then $x=at_1$ for some $t_1\in T$.

We have $\pi(x)=\pi(at_1)=\pi(a)\pi(t_1)$.

So

$$\pi(x)T/K=(at_1K)T/K \\=\{aKt_1KtK\;|\; t\in T  \}=\{ aKt'K  \; | \;    t'\in T\}\\=\{at'K\; | \; t'\in T\}=\pi(a)T/K=\pi(b)T/K$$

We get $\pi(x)T/K=\pi(b)T/K$.

Hence, for $xK\in\pi(x)T/K=\pi(b)T/K$, $$xK=bKtK=btK \text{ for some } t\in T \\\iff(bt)^{-1}x=k \text{ for some } k \in K \iff t^{-1}b^{-1}x=k \\\iff x=btk\in bT \text{ since $K\le T$}$$

Therefore $aT\subseteq bT$ is done, and similarly for the other side, we get $aT=bT$.

To prove that $f$ is surjective.

For any element in $(S/K)\;/\;(T/K)$, it has a form $\pi(s)(T/K)$.

Since $\pi$ is surjective, there is an element in $S$ such that $f(sT)=\pi(s)(T/K)$.

Hence, $f$ is bijective and $[S:T] =[S/K:T/K]$.

Is my argument correct?

Thanks for helping